# Noisy Data Robustness - NN vs Decision Tree

Tags: decision-trees

We are working on a physiological marker predictor using hospital patient data. We use a boosted decision tree-type algorithm, which seems to be very sensitive to the noise in the training data. Would it be fair to say the NN's are less sensitive to noisy data than decision trees?

Answer (score 1):

It is not fair to say that Decision Trees are more sensitive to noise in the data comparing to NN.

It really depends on your model type (DT, NN, SVM, ... etc) and **the model complexity**. in general, complex models have higher tendency to overfit (overfitting == sensitive to noise in the data). You can adjust the parameters of the DT, for example the max depth and see if this is affecting your results.

If you are training a classifier, try to use random forest, random forest are known to be very resistance to noise (overfitting).

If you give the NN more capacity, more layers and wider layers, the network will also overfit and become sensitive to noise **if you train for a long time**.

**Please note:**
DT training stops based on specific criteria that controls the model size.
based on these parameters, e.g., the max depth, the model can overfit, training will take longer time.

NN training stops based on training parameters, for example, the number of iterations, the stopping criteria, and not the complexity. To overfit, you will need to have both complex model and train for a long time. If the model is not sensitive to noise, it can be because, it is not complex enough or training for few number of iterations.